# How can i multiply a cell value of a dataframe based on two condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, iteration

I have this dataframe

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {'month': ['5','5','6', '7'], 'condition': ["yes","no","yes","yes"],'amount': [500,200, 500, 500]}
```

and two values:

```
inflation5 = 1.05
inflation6 = 1.08
inflation7 = 1.08
```

I need to know how can i multiply the cells of column 'amount' by the value inflation5 when the column 'month' value is 5 and the column 'condition' value is "yes", and also multiply the cells of column 'amount' by the value inflation6 when the column 'month' value is 6 and the column 'condition' value is "yes", and the same with month 7. But i need that calculation for the month 6 is based in the new calculated value of month 5, and the calculation for the month 7 is based in the new calculated value of month 6.
In order to explain this better, the value 500 is an estimation that needs to be updated with mensual inflation (accumulative).
The expected output for column 'amount': [525,200, 567, 612.36]

Thanks

Comment: what would happen if the value for `6` was `300`? should it change the outcome of the month `7`? and if the condition for month `6` was `no`?

Comment: The value for 6 and 7 neccesarily have to be the same as for 5. This is because in the real dataframe im doing an estimatation for several months based in the month 5. So in the first step, all month values are the same (for the cells tha meet the condition "yes"). In the second step, i need to apply the inflation rate to all subsequent months, in an accumulative way

Comment: OK but my point is how do we know which values go together? How does this generalize with more values? Check my update and let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use a different approach for efficiency.

Use a dictionary to store the inflations, then you can simply update in a single vectorial call:

```
inflations = {'5': 1.05, '6': 1.08}

mask = df['condition'].eq('yes')
df.loc[mask, 'amount'] *= df.loc[mask, 'month'].map(inflations)
```

*NB. if you possibly have missing months in the dictionary, use `df.loc[mask, 'month'].map(inflations).fillna(1)` in place of `df.loc[mask, 'month'].map(inflations)`*

output:

```
  month condition  amount
0     5       yes     525
1     5        no     200
2     6       yes    6480
3     7        no    1873
```

##### updated question: cumulated inflation

You can craft a series and use a `cumprod`:

```
inflations = {'5': 1.05, '6': 1.08, '7': 1.08}

mask = df['condition'].eq('yes')
s = pd.Series(inflations).cumprod()
df.loc[mask, 'amount'] *= df.loc[mask, 'month'].map(s).fillna(1)
```

Output:

```
  month condition  amount
0     5       yes  525.00
1     5        no  200.00
2     6       yes  567.00
3     7       yes  612.36
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i´ve updated the question because i´ve realizaed i´ve missed one step.

Comment: @Fernando can you provide the expected output for clarity?

Comment: Thanks, please also answer the comments to the question as this impacts the logic/solution.

Comment: Check the update, but difficult to know if this will generalize on your real dataset.

Answer (score 0):

For this I would run through with an np.where, should make it easily readable, and expandable especially if you wanted to change the condition with a function.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Inflation'] = np.where((df['month'] == '5') & (df['condition'] == 'yes'), inflation5, 1)
df['Inflation'] = np.where((df['month'] == '6') & (df['condition'] == 'yes'), inflation6, df['Inflation'])
df['Total_Amount'] = df['amount'].values * df['Inflation'].values
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i´ve updated the question because i´ve realizaed i´ve missed one step.